# What work flow would you follow to maintain a clean Arch Distro?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, bluetooth, systemctl

I recently Installed Arch Linux. I noticed that many services were no preinstalled in most Distro. For e.g. the bluetooth was not enabled by default in EndeavourOS. ditto with wifi. I don't mind that at all as I get to learn about many service like `bluetoothctl` etc.

However, I did notice that system maintenance is a very detailed process in Arch. For e.g. having read the Arch wiki on system maintenance one understand that some of the below action must be regularly undertaken.

1. Check for any failed systemD services`systemctl --failed`
2. Check for journal overload `journalctl -p 3 -b`
3. Remove orphaned packages `sudo pacman -Rns $(pacman -Qtdq)`
4. Remove cache files and dependencies `sudo pacman -Sc`
5. Package updates `sudo pacman -Syu`

Is this the same case with other Linux Distros or is this specific to Arch ? What is your experience of maintenance overhead in Arch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is too tedious and prefer to have control over it instead of automation.

- Make sure to check for pacnew files.
  https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman/Pacnew_and_Pacsave

  You will be noticed about the new file and it requires manual intervention.
- arch-audit is a helpful tool that shows risks associated with installed packages.
- Reflector is a simple tool to get a updated mirror list

Comment: Bravo many thanks